# Play Framework: How to use the reverse routes in an asset file?

Tags: angularjs, playframework

I have the following files for an application with Play Framework and AngularJs:

```
app/views/index.scala.html
app/assets/app/app.js
app/assets/app/app.scss
app/assets/app/main/_main.scss
app/assets/app/main/main.controller.js
app/assets/app/main/main.html
app/assets/app/main/main.js
app/assets/components/navbar/navbar.controller.js
app/assets/components/navbar/navbar.directive.js
app/assets/components/navbar/navbar.html
```

The `scss` files are in `app/assets`, so that the `sbt-sassify` plugin compiles them to `css`. and the other views (`js` and and `html` files) are also in `app/assets`, but I could move them to public.

The `conf/routes` contains:

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

The `navbar.directive.js` is as follows:

```
angular.module('quotesApp')
  .directive('navbar', () => ({
    templateUrl: 'components/navbar/navbar.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: 'NavbarController',
    controllerAs: 'nav'
  }));
```

This will not work, because the templateUrl `components/navbar/navbar.html`  path needs to be prefixed by `/assets/`, as defined in the `conf/routes` file.

So, what is the correct form to fix this?

Should I hard-code the prefix `/assets` in the file `navbar.directive.js`, as follows? However, this would be broken when changing the routes definition.

```
angular.module('quotesApp')
  .directive('navbar', () => ({
    templateUrl: '/assets/components/navbar/navbar.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: 'NavbarController',
    controllerAs: 'nav'
  }));
```

Should I create a view `app/views/components/navbar/navbar.directive.scala.js` (but this would be a lot of boilerplate only for using the `routes` function):

```
@()
angular.module('quotesApp')
  .directive('navbar', () => ({
    templateUrl: @routes.Assets.versioned("components/navbar/navbar.html"),
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: 'NavbarController',
    controllerAs: 'nav'
  }));
```

Any other solution? Maybe a relative path somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You can just define that path in your `index.scala.html`, before you need it in your angular directive:

```
<head>
    <!-- Something -->
    <script>
        window.MyApp = {
            'navBarPath': '@routes.Assets.versioned("components/navbar/navbar.html")';
        };
    </script>
</head>
```

And then in your directive use:

```
// (...)
templateUrl: MyApp.navBarPath,
```

It's not perfect, but I think it is the easiest way to achieve what you want.